# Why does the error appear: Sqlite3.Operational error: there is no column named name in the users table?

Tags: sqlite

I'm a novice programmer, I decided to make a bot on the telebot library, but an error occurred that there is no name column in the table. I will be grateful for your help.

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback:callback.data)
def check_callback(callback):
    if callback.data == 'moryak':
        conn = sqlite3.connect('users.sql')
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE users (
        id INTEGER autoincrement PRIMARY KEY,
        name TEXT, 
        title TEXT, 
        salary INTEGER,
        exper INTEGER, 
        age INTEGER,
        sea TEXT,
        dwt TEXT, 
        motor TEXT, 
        eng TEXT,
        tele TEXT,
        email TEXT,
        trip TEXT, 
        seek TEXT, 
        extra TEXT
        )""")
        conn.commit()
        cur.close()
        conn.close()

    
         @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
         def finish(message):
             extra = message.text.strip()

             conn = sqlite3.connect('users.sql')
             cur = conn.cursor()
             cur.execute(f'INSERT INTO users (name, title, salary, exper, age, sea, dwt, motor, eng, tele, email, trip, seek, extra) VALUES ("{name}", "{title}", "{salary}", "{exper}", "{age}", "{sea}", "{dwt}", "{motor}", "{eng}", "{tele}", "{email}", "{trip}", "{seek}", "{extra}")')
             conn.commit()
             cur.close()
             conn.close()
```

I tried using the "DROP TABLE" command, but it doesn't work. My code creates a table with **only** 1 "id" column.

Comment: It should be `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement`

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion you need to include the language you are using YES we are good at guessing Here is how I create a SQLite DB and a number of tables

Declare a few top level variables

```
Public Class frmNewData
Public connStr As String = "Data Source={0};Version=3;"
Public conn As SQLiteConnection
```

Now when the form loads

```
Private Sub frmNewData_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    connStr = String.Format(connStr, gv_dbName)
```

I use Module to declare global variables ie gv_dbName
You might like to read about Module and global variables
I have a button that calls MakeDB code below

```
   Private Sub btnMakeDB_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMakeDB.Click
    makeDB()
    btnMakeDB.Visible = False
    btnSave.Visible = True
    btnGet.Visible = True
    tbBeginBal.ReadOnly = False
    tbDepositAmt.ReadOnly = False
    tbDate.ReadOnly = False
End Sub
```

Now lets look at what makeDB does
It creates the DB and a number of tables

```
    Public Sub makeDB()

    If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(gv_dbName) Then
        Try
            conn = New SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{gv_dbName}';Version=3;")
            conn.Open()
            makeDateInfo()
            makeSSData()
            makeCBBalance()
            makeTxData()

        Catch ex As Exception
            tbMessage.Text = "DB and Tables NOT Created"
        End Try
    End If

End Sub
```

OK here is how one of the tables is created

```
    Public Sub makeSSData()

    Dim create_table As String = String.Empty
    create_table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SSDataTable(
                    SID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                    ssAmount TEXT,
                    ssType TEXT,
                    ssDesc TEXT)"

    Dim dbTable As String = "SSDataTable"

    If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(dbTable) Then
        Try
            Using conn As New SQLiteConnection(connStr)
                conn.Open()
                Using cmd As New SQLiteCommand(create_table, conn)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            tbMessage.Text = "SSData Table FAILED"
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

All this code in on one form called frmNewData.vb
And when the frmStart.vb loads it calls this frmNewData.vb to create the
necessary DB and Tables with this code

```
  Private Sub frmStart_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(gv_dbName) Then
        btnInit.Visible = False
        Me.Height = 525
        Me.Width = 900
        Me.Refresh()
    Else
        Me.Height = 200
        Me.Width = 480

        Me.Refresh()
        btnInit.Visible = True
        btnEnterCheck.Visible = False
        btnDeposit.Visible = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Once the DB is created and the tables are created
btnInit no longer shows up